# Mysql compare Strings

Tags: mysql, string, comparison

from a resultset of about 5 different strings, I would like to select the result of which the string resembles my given string the most. Is there any possibility to do this in mysql?

Comment: If you can show us the strings.. it would help a little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the perfect application of the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) metric.

It appears that there is at least one [UDF implementation](http://empyrean.lib.ndsu.nodak.edu/~nem/mysql/) of this metric, which may have fallen off the web, and another [SQL implementation](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1278#552).

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to achieve this using [SOUNDEX](http://www.madirish.net/?article=85)